# Examples of when PHP calls the function set by set_exception_handler with an Error object? And is it always fatal? Can it be caught?

Tags: php, error-handling, fatal-error, throwable

I'm trying to write a handler for exceptions. I've noticed that sometimes it's passed an Error object. (As opposed to an Exception object). I'd like to know:

1. Some examples of what triggers this to happen
2. Whether when an Error object is passed to the exception handler, is it always fatal?
3. Can the Error object being thrown be caught, stopping it from being fatal? And if it isn't caught, is it always fatal?

Thanks

Comment: Error is just an exception. Your handler will catch it all the same

Comment: The idea of custom handlers is being able to shut down application gracefully, so you're able to e.g. display a nice message to user or have the error properly logged. You aren't meant to use them to ignore errors and resume execution flow in the exact spot where the error was thrown (mainly because you can't physically do that). So the distinction between fatal and non-fatal does not really apply in this context.